# Can cut() be improved?

Tags: r, cut, radix

Currently the last 4 lines of `cut.default` are written as:

```
code <- .bincode(x, breaks, right, include.lowest)
if (codes.only) 
  code
else factor(code, seq_along(labels), labels, ordered = ordered_result)
```

Could this not be improved by rewriting it in the following way?

```
  code <- .bincode(x, breaks, right, include.lowest)
  if (!codes.only) {
    levels(code) <- as.character(labels)
    class(code) <- c(if (ordered_result) "ordered" else character(0), "factor")
  }
  code
}
```

If there's a reason this might not work or is simply a misguided approach I'd be happy to hear your thoughts.

It seems to improve performance for when the result is a factor (the default).

#### Small data

```
library(bench)

x <- as.double(1:100) + 0
breaks <- seq(0, 90, 7)
unsorted_breaks <- sample(breaks)
mark(cut.default(x, breaks), 
            cut2(x, breaks), 
     min_iterations = 10^4)
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>     <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 cut.default(x… 130µs  148µs     6372.    2.97KB     1.27  9998     2      1.57s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
2 cut2(x, break… 101µs  115µs     8082.      448B     2.43  9997     3      1.24s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>

mark(cut.default(x, unsorted_breaks), 
            cut2(x, unsorted_breaks),
     min_iterations = 10^4)
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>     <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 cut.default(x… 130µs  148µs     6328.    2.97KB     1.90  9997     3      1.58s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
2 cut2(x, unsor… 106µs  116µs     8281.      448B     1.66  9998     2      1.21s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

#### Larger data

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(10^6, 0, 10^5)
breaks <- seq(min(x), max(x), by = 5)

mark(cut.default(x, breaks),
            cut2(x, breaks))
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>     <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 cut.default(x… 1.78s  1.78s     0.561   113.9MB        0     1     0      1.78s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
2 cut2(x, break… 1.06s  1.06s     0.944    74.7MB        0     1     0      1.06s <fct>  <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>

x <- rnorm(10^7) + 0
b <- seq(0, max(x), 0.2) + 0

mark(e1 = cut.default(x, b),
     e2 = cut2(x, b))
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 e1            1.49s    1.49s     0.671     267MB    0.671     1     1      1.49s <fct> 
2 e2         282.39ms 303.67ms     3.29     38.1MB    0         2     0   607.34ms <fct> 
# ℹ 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

#### cut2

```
cut2 <- function (x, breaks, labels = NULL, include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
                  dig.lab = 3L, ordered_result = FALSE, ...){
  if (!is.numeric(x)) 
    stop("'x' must be numeric")
  if (length(breaks) == 1L) {
    if (is.na(breaks) || breaks < 2L) 
      stop("invalid number of intervals")
    nb <- as.integer(breaks + 1)
    dx <- diff(rx <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    if (dx == 0) {
      dx <- if (rx[1L] != 0) 
        abs(rx[1L])
      else 1
      breaks <- seq.int(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] + dx/1000, 
                        length.out = nb)
    }
    else {
      breaks <- seq.int(rx[1L], rx[2L], length.out = nb)
      breaks[c(1L, nb)] <- c(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] + 
                               dx/1000)
    }
  }
  else nb <- length(breaks <- sort.int(as.double(breaks)))
  if (anyDuplicated(breaks)) 
    stop("'breaks' are not unique")
  codes.only <- FALSE
  if (is.null(labels)) {
    for (dig in dig.lab:max(12L, dig.lab)) {
      ch.br <- formatC(0 + breaks, digits = dig, width = 1L)
      if (ok <- all(ch.br[-1L] != ch.br[-nb])) 
        break
    }
    labels <- if (ok) 
      paste0(if (right) 
        "("
        else "[", ch.br[-nb], ",", ch.br[-1L], if (right) 
          "]"
        else ")")
    else paste0("Range_", seq_len(nb - 1L))
    if (ok && include.lowest) {
      if (right) 
        substr(labels[1L], 1L, 1L) <- "["
      else substring(labels[nb - 1L], nchar(labels[nb - 
                                                     1L], "c")) <- "]"
    }
  }
  else if (is.logical(labels) && !labels) 
    codes.only <- TRUE
  else if (length(labels) != nb - 1L) 
    stop("number of intervals and length of 'labels' differ")
  code <- .bincode(x, breaks, right, include.lowest)
  if (!codes.only) {
    levels(code) <- as.character(labels)
    class(code) <- c(if (ordered_result) "ordered" else character(0), "factor")
  }
  code
}
```

Comment: This question is more suited for the [r-devel@r-project.org](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) mailing list. Quoting from that page: *"The list is also for discussing implementation details and proposals of new functionality for R"*.

Comment: Is this really a performance bottleneck for you? By manually setting class and levels you are assuming you have a deep understanding of the object internals. If you just farm that stuff out to `factor()` you have that knowledge more contained/encapsulated. Some design decisions aren't always about performance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
It's not a performance bottleneck for me per se, but I find that this code is simpler and avoids extra steps that I would argue are unnecessary. If you think this approach is incorrect I'd be happy to be shown an example of where this code would fail. 
Also given the wide use of `cut` I would personally argue the simplified, faster and more memory efficient code is justified.

Comment: Furthermore, the last benchmark shows a 7x difference in memory allocation and 4x difference in speed which is definitely noticeable.

Comment: @NicChr unsure what sort of answer you are looking for- if you've already demonstrated that your code works better than their code, then the answer is just going to be "yes, cut() can be improved", which idk if that helps anyone

Comment: I'm asking the question because I'm not sure if this code will work 100% of the time as expected and also to see what others think.